# Two alphabetic sequences

Tags: pattern, letter-sequence

Here are two alphabetic sequences:

```
A E F H I K L M N
B C D G J O P Q R
```

To which one would each of the remaining letters of the alphabet belong?

```
S T U V W X Y Z
```

And - why?

Comment: I see. Sorry, before posting I had searched for adequate keywords, but that one didn't show up. I did not intend this question to be a duplicate (or as in this case, a subset) of a riddle already solved.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Set 1

> T V W X Y Z

Set 2

> S U

The reasoning:

> Set one contains letters that are straight, set 2 contains curved letters

Comment: Excellent, and very quick!